# Enable TLS on BIND9

Tags: linux, dns, ssl, bind

I am trying to enable TLS on my BIND server (9.19.16) which is otherwise working fine. When I add the following code to enable TLS, then my BIND server does not start.

```
named.conf:

tls local-tls {
   cert-file "/path/to/cert.crt";
   key-file "/path/to/private.key";
};

options {
  listen-on port 853 tls local-tls { any; };
};
```

When I check the status of BIND, it does not give any specific errors, just says:

```
named.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Stopped BIND Domain Name Server.
named.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
named.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start BIND Domain Name Server.
```

When I use `journalctl -xeu named.service` to look at the status it just gives the same lines from above. My cert files are fine, they can be located just fine and apparmor is not causing any issues. What could be the problem as without TLS my BIND server starts just fine?

EDIT:
I checked syslog for any errors and this is the error message:

```
Error initializing TLS context: error:8000000D:system library::Permission denied
loading configuration: TLS error
```

Comment: Did you try enabling debug logging? Good article here: https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01526

Comment: @Edward I have editted my original post - please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by changing the extension of the certificate and key to .pem and moving them to `/var/cache/bind`